# Bijection of Modular Functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I don't quite understand how to apply the concept of bijections to functions in mod $n$. I understand that a bijection is a function that is both surjective and injective (unique pre-image and all elements in image hit), but I can't conceptualize it with functions via mod $n$, like :

$f(x)$ = $x + 1$ mod $m$.

How is this function bijective? It's not that I don't think it's not, I just can't visualize it. Any "dumbed down" explanation would be tremendously helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you think about modular arithmetic, I think it is helpful to think of it from the vaguely-group-theoretic point of view.  Or, alternatively, in terms of equivalence relations.

Equality modulo $m$ is an equivalence relation. It breaks up the integers into equivalence classes, which we can represent by $[0],[1],\ldots,[m-1]$, where
$$
[i]=\{x\in\mathbb{Z}\mid x\equiv i\pmod m\}=\{i+km\mid k\in\mathbb{Z}\}.
$$
When you say that the function $f(x)=x+1\pmod m$ is bijective, what you are really saying is that the function
$$
f:\{[0],\ldots,[m-1]\}\to\{[0],\ldots,[m-1]\}
$$
defined by
$$
f([i])=[i+1]
$$
(where we identify $[m]=[0]$, as is naturally the case as sets) is a bijection.

In other words: you are saying that $f$ is a bijective map on the equivalence classes.

Comment: So, would it be safe to say that all polynomials $f(x)$ in mod $n$ is a bijection, since you can always find an inverse right?

Comment: Not every polynomial is invertible mod $n$, any more than they are invertible in general.  For instance, consider $x^2$ modulo $4$.  This is defined by the map
$$
[0]\to[0],\quad [1]\to[1],\quad [2]\to[0],\quad [3]\to[1]
$$

Comment: Ah, alright, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> I just can't visualize it.

That's hard to answer in general, since we don't all *visualize* things the same way, even simple ones.

Maybe think of $x \bmod n$ as points on a circle, then $x+ 1 \bmod n$ would "shift" them cyclically.

Or maybe think of $f$ as a function which has an obvious inverse $f^{-1}(x)=x-1 \bmod m$, so that it must be a bijection.